# starpy click to call not calling

Tags: python, asterisk

Python framework starpy click to call, everything is configured properly but is not calling, having to mention i am using voip.ms.

from the url i fet it to call with this http://localhost:8000/?number=00593968196867&ext=101

everything is successfully and connects but it just doesn't call

```
from starpy import manager
from starpy.manager import AMIFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import server,resource

import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger("Click2Call")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
manager.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class Click2CallProtocol(object):
 def __init__(self):
     pass
 def onConnect(self,ami):
     log.info("Logged in successfully")
     self.ami = ami

 def dial(self,number,ext):
     try:
            # here goes the SIP configuretion details and the number you call
         self.ami.originate(channel='Local/101@mycontext',context='mycontext',priority='1',exten=ext,async=True)
         return True
     except:
         return False



class Click2CallFactory(AMIFactory):

 def __init__(self):
    # the user and password from manager.conf
     AMIFactory.__init__(self,"admin","Admin")

 def connect(self):
     df = self.login("127.0.0.1")
     df.addCallback(c2cp.onConnect)

 def clientConnectionLost(self,connector,reason):
     log.info("We lost connection trying reconnect")
     reactor.callLater(1,self.connect)

 def clientConnectionFailed(self,connector,reason):
     log.info(reason)
     reactor.callLater(1,self.connect)

class Click2CallResource(resource.Resource):

 def render(self,request):
     try:
         number = request.args['number'][0]
         agent =  request.args['ext'][0]
     except:
         return "Required arguments not found"
     if c2cp.dial(agent,number):
         return "OK"
     else:
         return "NOTOK"

c2cp = Click2CallProtocol()
c2cf = Click2CallFactory()
c2cf.connect()

root = Click2CallResource()
root.putChild("",root)
site = server.Site(root)

reactor.listenTCP(8000,site,)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This **Local/101@mycontext** should be valid dialstraing. i.e you need have mycontext and ext 101 in it.

Why you use twisted, factory etc etc for such simple one liner task?

Comment: Hi thanks, everything seems to be configured properly but i still don't have any calls from asterisk, yes i have that configured correctly in extentions.conf and also the sip member in sip.conf i can make calls 
 with zoiper correctly, but i am a bit new in asterisk and click to call so i followed this guide.https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-python-starpy-click-to-call/

Comment: debug is offtopic on SO. You code look too way complex for me for this task, try something other. Start from asterisk cli command Originate for example and asterisk book.